# Convert array of objects to TSV format using JavaScript (No online tools)

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

Array:

`[{"username":"admin","datetime":"27/10/2018 11:27","password":"12345"}]`

To

TSV Format:

```
username    datetime    password
admin   27/10/2018 11:27    12345
```

I have Googled, but mostly I find online tools for above. Can anybody suggest script for this, thanks in advance.

> Disclaimer: My application work's without internet, so internet dependency are not work here.

Comment: papaparse will probably do what you want

Comment: Is there any JavaScript snippet, that convert array of objects to TSV? Expet Plugins and online tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convertArrayTSV() {
    let result, ctr, keys, label, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter;

    let data = [{ "username": "admin", "datetime": "27/10/2018 11:27", "password": "12345" }];

    columnDelimiter = '  ';
    lineDelimiter = '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    label = ["username", "datetime", "password"];
    result = '';
    result += label;
    result += lineDelimiter;
    let no = 1;

    data.forEach(function (item) {
        ctr = 1;
        keys.forEach(function (key) {
            if (ctr > 1) result += columnDelimiter;
            if (key === 'username') {
                let str = item[key];
                result += str;
                ctr++;
            } else if (key === 'datetime') {
                let str = item[key];
                result += str;
                ctr++;
            } else if (key === 'password') {
                let str = item[key];
                result += str;
                ctr++;
            }
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
        no++;
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(convertArrayTSV());
```

O/P :

```
username,datetime,password 
admin  27/10/2018 11:27  12345
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{"username":"admin","datetime":"27/10/2018 11:27","password":"12345"},{"username":"admin2","datetime":"22/11/2018 11:27","password":"admin2"}];

// grab the column headings (separated by tabs)
const headings = Object.keys(data[0]).join('\t');

// iterate over the data
const rows = data.reduce((acc, c) => {
  
  // for each row object get its values and add tabs between them
  // then add them as a new array to the outgoing array
  return acc.concat([Object.values(c).join('\t')]);

// finally joining each row with a line break
}, []).join('\n');

// display the result (here with `innerText` because
// `textContent` doesn't recognise styling)
document.body.innerText = `${headings}\n${rows}`;
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; ]
```